# Java Concurrency (Multithreading) - parallel() outcomes differ with tryLock()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

In the below code total is always 45, but total1 is unpredictable. I feel total should be unpredictable too as threads are not depending whether lock is acquired by tryLock() or not. Please can anybody explain what is the difference in calculation of total and total1.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class HelloWorld{
               
   private Lock vault = new ReentrantLock();
   private int total = 0;
   private int total1 = 0;

   public void deposit(int value) {
       try {
           vault.tryLock();
           total += value;
       } 
       finally {
           vault.unlock();
       }
   }
                      
   public void add(int val) {
       total1 += val;
   }

   public static void main(String[] unused) {
       HelloWorld bank = new HelloWorld();

       IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(s -> bank.deposit(s));

       System.out.println(bank.total);  //   45
                            
       HelloWorld bank1 = new HelloWorld();
       AtomicLong value1 = new AtomicLong(0);
       final long[] value2 = {0};
       IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 1).limit(100)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(i -> value1.incrementAndGet());
       IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 1).limit(100)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(i -> ++value2[0]);   
       IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 1).limit(100)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(i -> bank1.add(i));
       System.out.println(value1+" "+value2[0]+" " +bank1.total1); // 100 94(Unpredictable) 96 (Unpredictable)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I feel total should be unpredictable too as threads are not depending whether lock is acquired by tryLock() or not.

I think you are right... Sort of.

Your program seems to *allow* different threads to access `total` with no synchronization (i.e., when `vault.tryLock()` happens to fail), but just because it is allowed to happen, that's not a guarantee that it actually *will* happen.

Testing for concurrency-related bugs sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't work. The Java language spec and the javadoc for the standard Java library guarantee certain behaviors if your program obeys certain rules, but they do *not* guarantee that your program will behave "wrongly" if it *breaks* the rules. They *allow* it, but they don't guarantee it.

Comment: Yes as tryLock() running successfully we are getting same result on each run if due to some reason it is not able to get the lock then unlock() will give error I guess. Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

To make things confusing `total` and `total1` aren't even calculating the same thing:

- `total` is trying to compute `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9`
- `total1` is trying to compute `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + ...`

If we just consider the threading though:

- `total` calls the `deposit` method which is guarded by the lock.
- `total1` calls the `add` method which is not guarded.

Therefore `total` is predictable because the lock means only one thread at a time can do the add operation, but `total1` is unpredictable because many threads could be doing each add operation at the same time.

Comment: Now i understood as tryLock() is succeeding each time we are able to get same result in each run. Thanks